$\inf_{a, b \in \mathbb{R}} \left( (1-a-b)^2 + (1-3a+b)^2 + (1-2a-b)^2 \right)$
Find $y = \inf_{a, b \in \mathbb{R}} \left( (1-a-b)^2 + (1-3a+b)^2 + (1-2a-b)^2 \right)$.
This is a problem is in a course of biliear algebra and scalar products.
Since it's about an inf, I thought about interpreting it as a distance between a vector and its projection.  But I don't really know where to go from here. I don't know on what subspace I should project, and I don't know how to find the scalar product, I know this equation looks like a quadratic form, but I can't figure out what to do.
Any help please?

The simplest method is expanding all the term. Then there would be no $ab$ term, so $L = (1-a-b)^2 + (1-3a+b)^2 + (1-2a-b)^2$ would be sum of two independent quadratic. You can easily find global minimum of $L(x,y)$ and where it happens.

@MH.Lee  I thought about doing that and then using partial derivatives I get a system of two equations and just solve and substitute, it should give 75. But I have to do it using scalar products.

Let $L=(1-a-b)^2 + (1-3a+b)^2 + (1-2a-b)^2$, then it would be square of distance $P(a+b,3a-b,2a+b)$ and $A(1,1,1)$.
Regardless of the value $a,b$, $P$ lies a plane $\pi$ in $\mathbb R^3$ which generated by $u=(1,3,2), v=(1, -1, 1)$ and pass through origin. The equation of the plane is not the interest, but its normal vector does. It is $n=(5, 1, -4)$.
Since $n,u,v$ are linear independent, so vector $OA = \lambda n+\mu u+\eta v$. Using scalar product, then you can get the value of $\lambda$, and length of $\lambda n$ is very same with minimal distance of $\pi$ and $A$, which is $\sqrt {\inf L}$.
I'm not sure that this is what you disred. But it's definitely a way to solve this problem with scalar products.

So I calculated the orthogonal projection of $(1,1,1)$ onto $(5,1,-4)$, I found $\left( \frac{5}{21}, \frac{1}{21}, -\frac{4}{21} \right)$.
The value of $y$ (the inf) is the square of the norm of this vector? Basically its dot product with itself, right?

Yes, almost. But not $\frac{1}{21}(5,1,-4)$ but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{21}}(5,1,-4)$.

Why the square root? Isn't the projection $\frac{v \cdot u}{|u|^2} \cdot u = \frac{2}{42} * u= \frac{1}{21} * \left( 5, 1, -4 \right)$. Here v is (1,1,1) and u is the normal vector.

@mmmmhmmmmmh Oh yes, I mislead. Sorry for that.
